# Can't use the resolution by name with kube-dns

Tags: dns, docker, kubernetes

I'm on a kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes that are all VM and they use to communicate a bridge that is an Only-Host interface:
192.168.99.101 master
192.168.99.102 and .103 the other nodes I have used to create the cluster kubeadm and I have passed this addiction paramethers_ `--api-advertise-address=192.168.99.101`

Now, if I use them in my application the IP of the services that connect me to a deploy it works fine, but if I try to use the name of the same services I can't find it(but I see that:

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   57m
```

i use this guide to [solve](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) and i have find that errors but i don't knwo how to solve:

```
vmmaster@vmmaster-VirtualBox:~/Documenti/Tesi/NFS$  kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
command terminated with exit code 1
```

i have follow the next step, i copy only the things with logs W F and E because they are the erro logs:

```
    kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c kubedns
    E0516 15:55:28.781740       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:150: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
    E0516 15:55:28.782057       1 reflector.go:201] k8s.io/dns/pkg/dns/dns.go:147: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout

    kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c dnsmasq
    W0516 15:54:59.341790       1 nanny.go:120] Got EOF from stdout
```

and:

```
        kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system $(kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns -o name) -c sidecar
    W0516 15:54:59.233531       1 server.go:64] Error getting metrics from dnsmasq: read udp 127.0.0.1:54118->127.0.0.1:53: read: connection refused
```

can someone help me?